# How to convert string to float if it is an exact number, not only start with number in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make function that check strings. If the string is number, then it will convert it as float. else, it will keep it as it is.

For example: I have these test strings:

```
"123" => 123
"12.3" => 12.3
"12.300" => 12.3
"test123" => "test123"
"123test" => "123test"
"12.3test" => "12.3test"
"123@123.123" => "123@123.123"
```

I tried to make it by self as written bellow but sometime it convert real strings to numbers by remove the letters and keep the first part of string numbers

```
let mynumber="123test@gmail.com"
mynumber = parseFloat(mynumber) ? parseFloat(mynumber) : mynumber;
//output: 123
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could convert your string to a number with `Number()` and also check if its NaN.

```js
function check(num){
   return isNaN(Number(num)) ? num : Number(num);
}

let mynumber="123test@gmail.com"
let mynumber2 = "34234";
let mynumber3 = "3234.234";

let result = check(mynumber);
let result2 = check(mynumber2);
let result3 = check(mynumber3);


console.log(result, typeof result);
console.log(result2, typeof result2);
console.log(result3, typeof result3);
```

Comment: Tested. Works fine. Thanks Ifaruki

Comment: Your answer is very good. Please let me know for using Number inside isNaN()   on conditional,   isNaN(Number(num))

Comment: @MuhammadUmarFarooq actually... you dont need `Number()` inside the conditional

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to like below

```
let mynumber="123test@gmail.com"
mynumber = isNaN(mynumber)?mynumber:parseFloat(mynumber)
```

here isNaN will check for valid number

Answer (score 0):

You can use `isNan` which checks if the argument is `NaN` or not.

```
let mynumber="123test@gmail.com"
 isNaN(mynumber)
//output: true


let mynumber="123.123"
 isNaN(mynumber)
//output: false
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply add + symbol before any string, it will convert it to number.

```
var a = "10.25";

console.log( +a );
```

Output: 10.25

Comment: This will fail for most input/outputs shown in the question.